# Php search engine not working?

Tags: php, mysql, search, mysqli

I'm working on a simple search engine that gets you information but I'm having a problem. You see when I put a space into the search input it doesn't give you the message saying "no key words searched please try again" but when you click the search button without adding anything in the search input it works. How could i fix this to make it work with both?

Code:

```
if(!$db) {
    die('sorry we are having some problbems');
}


$searchTerm = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['term']);

if ( empty($searchTerm))
{
echo("no key words searched please try again");
}
else
{
$sql = mysqli_query(
    $db,
    sprintf(
        "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE name LIKE '%s' LIMIT 0,20",
        '%'. $searchTerm .'%'
    )
);

while($ser = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<a href='$ser[pageurl]'>$ser[img]</a>";
}
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: `"sorry we are having some problbems"`

Answer (score 3):

Use `trim()` to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
$searchTerm = trim($searchTerm);

if ($searchTerm == '') {
    echo("no key words searched please try again");
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for whitespace in addition to the empty search term. Here I'm using the regular expressions [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to find any whitespace characters that could be entered.

```
if (empty($searchTerm)||preg_match('!^\s+$!',$searchTerm))
  {
    echo("no key words searched please try again");
  }
else...
```

Or with preg_match alone

```
if (preg_match('!^\s*$!',$searchTerm))
  {
    echo("no key words searched please try again");
  }
else...
```

Another method you could use is to check the string length using [strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

```
if (strlen($searchTerm)<4)
  {
    echo("no key words searched please try again");
  }
else...
```

Comment: Don't you mean `^\s*$`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It's been a rough day.

Comment: You still need `*`, otherwise you're only checking for a single space, not all spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query instead of using sprintf

```
    "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE name LIKE '%$searchsting%' LIMIT 0,20"
```

Comment: How does that solve the problem of the search string containing just spaces?